# Trigger delete on many-to-many middle table deletion

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are two tables `A` and `B`. As they have a many-to-many relation, there's also table `C`.

```
A
------
id PK


B
------
id PK

C
------
id_A PK
id_B PK
```

Now, a row `B` only exists only exists when at least one row of `A` has a relation to it, and one `B` may contain a relation to two or more different rows of `A`.

My question is, how do i automatically delete a row from `B` if there isn't any foreign to it in `C`? My initial though was to set a trigger, but i'm not to sure about this and i'd want a second opinion in how to proceed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, one assumes that the data is initially set up correctly.  That is, the only `b` records are the ones that meet your condition.

Then, the solution involves triggers on table `c`.  When a row is deleted, it would check:

- Does `id_b` have any other rows in the table?
- If not, then delete the row.

This can actually be a bit tricky.  In general, you don't want to query the table being triggered.  So, I might suggest an alternative approach:

- Add a counter on `b`.
- Add insert/update/delete triggers on c that increments or decrements the count in `b`.
- If the counter is `0` (or `1` before decrementing), then delete the row.

Gosh, you might find that the counter itself is sufficient, and there is no need to actually delete the row.  You can get that effect if you use a view:

```
create view v_b as
    select b.*
    from b
    where ab_counter > 0;
```

You could also create a view on `b` and not have to deal with triggers at all:

```
create view v_b as
    select b.*
    from b
    where exists (select 1 from c where c.b_id = b.id);
```

Comment: Thanks! My first thought was to do how you described it first, but the alternative seems the way to go. However, why do you generally avoid querying the triggered table?

Answer (score 1):

@Gordon's solution above is great, However a slight modification might help.

First, one assumes that the data is initially set up correctly. That is, the only b records are the ones that meet your condition.

Then, the solution involves triggers on table c. When a row is deleted, it would check:

- Does id_b have any other rows in the table?
- If not, then delete the
  row.

This is a bit tricky because you have to check if other rows exist. This check can be automated by using,

```
FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES B(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

on table C. Now you only need to delete row from B in the trigger without any checks, since the restrict constraint will automatically check if row exists in table C and restrict the delete of a referenced row in table B else delete is successful.

Comment: While this solution provides a simpler way to solve my problem, the response by @Gordon works better for me because i'm using an ORM which only deletes the rows from C, and therefore deleting B automatically. Thanks eitherway!

Comment: I don't get it. How does deleting row from C automatically deletes a row from B unless you specify on delete cascade or its default of your ORM. That said, The soft delete @Gordon suggested is definitely a good strategy to use :)

Comment: Because when arow in `C` is deleted, a trigger decreases the the counter in `B` and if result is 0, deletes it.

Comment: Well if you are eitherway not using soft delete, you get that in restrict delete version you would only have to write one trigger which deletes B (no counters nothing and no checks just "delete from B where id=id_B"). When your ORM deletes C, the trigger will delete B directly. And the restrict constraint will not allow it if rows in C exist (automatically). basically you delete C -> trigger try to delete B -> succeeds if B doesn't exist in C else fails.